# Get Error '...' object has no attribute '_default_manager' when call API

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

I get error **'Person' object has no attribute '_default_manager'** when try to call API http://127.0.0.1:8000/people/create-by-god/.
And I don't know why, because I set null, blank and default at values I dont send in request.
Help me! please

Here is my source
Model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    GENDER = [
        ('XX', 'Female'),
        ('XY', 'Male'),
    ]
    STATUS = [
        (0, 'Death'),
        (1, 'Alive'),
    ]
    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER,blank=False, null=False)
    father = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)
    mother = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    local = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    statu = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Serializer

```
class FirstPersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'local']
```

Views

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    
    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False, url_path='create-by-god', url_name='create-by-god')
    def create_by_god(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.serializer_class = FirstPersonSerializer
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Error log

```
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response     
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view    
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception       
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\NhatNDQ\training\training-django\my_big_world\world\views\person.py", line 13, in create_by_god
    return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 18, in create
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 220, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 421, in run_validation   
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 454, in run_validators   
    super().run_validators(to_validate)
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 578, in run_validators        
    for validator in self.validators:
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 408, in validators
    self._validators = self.get_validators()
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 1500, in get_validators  
    self.get_unique_for_date_validators()
  File "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 1576, in get_unique_for_date_validators
    default_manager = self.Meta.model._default_manager
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: Could you try removing the `related_name` values on both `mother/father` foreign keys?

Comment: I try remove them and get error ```ERRORS:
world.Person.father: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Person.father' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Person.mother'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Person.father' or 'Person.mother'.
world.Person.mother: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Person.mother' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Person.father'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Person.mother' or 'Person.father'.```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I just remove `()` like that:

```
class FirstPersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person #before is Person()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'local']
```